# d3 v4 error this.setAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to convert the following example to be d3 v4 compatible http://bl.ocks.org/ameyms/9184728

I have been able to convert almost all of it, but I am having trouble with the following function:

```
  this.el.transition().delay(100).duration(200).select('.needle').tween('reset-progress', function() {
    return function(percentOfPercent) {
      var progress = (1 - percentOfPercent) * oldValue;

      repaintGauge(progress);
      return d3.select(this).attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(self, progress));
    };
  });
```

The error I'm getting is `this.setAttribute is not a function` on the line with the return. I've verified that `recalcPointerPos` is working correctly, so I think the issue is with the d3.select(this).attr syntax. Did something change for this type of selection between v3 and v4?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v1tok1k6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inner return select has the wrong `this` scope for selecting the element. What you want is the outer functions `this`, which represents the `path` element. I'd do the select on the outer scope for caching.

```js
this.el.transition().delay(300).duration(1500).select('.needle').tween('progress', function(d, i, e) {
  var needle = d3.select(this);
  return function(percentOfPercent) {
    var progress = percentOfPercent * perc;

    repaintGauge(progress);
    return needle.attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(self, progress));
  };
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1tok1k6/1/)